# What is the need of the struct thread_info in locating struct task_struct?

Tags: linux, kernel, process, c, multithreading

While reading through the Linux Device Drivers, I could understand that the Process Descriptor (of type `struct task_struct`) has all the info regarding a particular task. The process descriptors are allocated dynamically by the slab allocator.

What I would like to know is about the need to introduce a new structure called `thread_info` which is stored at the bottom of the stack (assuming x86). Why was this done?

Why was it not possible to place the address of the current executing task address (`struct task_struct`) to the kernel stack?

Comment: the thread_info's size is smaller, such that can reserve more space for stack.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why we need the **thread_info** is due to the fact that we are allocating the memory for **task_struct** using the Slab Allocator. Now you may ask what is the relation between these?

To understand that you need to understand how Slab Allocator works.

Without the Slab Allocator , the kernel developers could allocate memory for **task_struct** in the kernel stack for the particular process so that it can be accessed easily. Now with the advent of Slab Allocator , the memory is allocated to the **task_struct** as determined by the Slab Allocator. So with the Slab Allocator you have **task_struct** stored somewhere else and not in the kernel stack of the particular process. Now the Kernel developers introduced **thread_info** and placed a pointer in it to the place where the **task_struct** resides. And that is why we have to live with **thread_info**.

You can read about Slab Allocator in Robert Love's book Linux Kernel Development.

Answer (score -4):

[Light-weight processes](http://www.makelinux.net/books/ulk3/understandlk-CHP-3-SECT-1) don't have a `task_struct`; a stack and a small amount of information would be enough. Several LWPs share the same `task_struct`, which contains all the resource descriptions.

Comment: In linux kernel, `taks_struct` and `thread_info` is 1-1 mapping.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. According to the kernel implementation, LWP also has a task_struct.